# Do any SVN servers exist for Android?

Tags: web-server

Just upgraded to a new phone. So, I have my old one with a cracked screen lying around. Is there any way to run an SVN server on it for a few projects I am working on with a friend?

Its low power and small size makes it ideal for a task like this.

Answer (score 1):

[One SVN app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valleytg.oasvnlite.android&hl=en) is available in Google Play.

But I think it can work as SVN Client only,
I haven't tried it though.